# In Excel, how do I highlight all rows that do not contain “,2”?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm verifying the `FormatCurrency` function is written properly in ASP code and I put everything in Excel from "find results".

I want to highlight only the ones that do not contain ",2" in them.

- **Don't highlight this:** `styResult = FormatCurrency(TotalCostOfOwnership, 2)`
- **Highlight this:** `strResult = FormatCurrency(TotalRevenueStream, 8, 3)`
- **Don't hightlight this:** `styResult = FormatCurrency(TotalCreditsReceived,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then Conditional Formatting should work very nicely for you.

Briefly, with this feature, you set up one or more rules, each of which:

- Identifies which cells you want the rule to format (e.g. 'does not contain ,2')
- the format to apply

This [tutorial](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/how_to_use_conditional_formatting_to_highlight_data) describes it well, and has some links to videos, one of which (at the end) is specifically for Excel 2003.